# ASP.NET C#, SQL Rendering images, sql query etc 

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Im creating a military site for an organisation. A part of the site is going to be a news/blog-wall.

The news are going to consist of an simpel article and for that article a few picture depending on what the article-writer is choosing.

In my database i made up two tables, one for news and one for pictures. Connected these together, the picture table consist only the URL for the picture, not the whole picture.

Now for the problem:

If there is only ONE picture connected to article everything works fine but if i get several pictures i get several rows for each picture but same article.

This gives me the next problem, my ASP.NET ListView things its a new article and renders out one picture per article and the same article text >.<

Ive been asking my teacher in uni for help but they seem all busy with other lectures.

I also wonder how to render out multiple pictures in ListView, got to use some foreach in code-behinde to get more image tags i guess but how?

Ill post this picture of my SQL query if it helps, look at row 2 and 3.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLatestNews] AS 
BEGIN 
   SELECT News.NyhetID, News.Rubrik, News.Nyhet, News.Datum, Picture.Picture 
   FROM Picture
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN News as News ON News.NyhetID = Picture.NyhetID 
   ORDER BY News.NyhetID DESC 
END
```

Thanks all in advance and remember im a novice programmer, this is maybe very easy? Im really torn about this as it can't be that hard I'm tellin myself.

Comment: If you can update your question with just the text of the query (rather than a picture), you might get more specific responses.

Comment: Just use WordPress for this and that's it...

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLatestNews] AS BEGIN SELECT News.NyhetID, News.Rubrik, News.Nyhet, News.Datum, Picture.Picture FROM Picture RIGHT OUTER JOIN News as News ON News.NyhetID = Picture.NyhetID ORDER BY News.NyhetID DESC END EXEC dbo.GetLatestNews I get something like: Row|NyhetID|Rubrik|Nyhet|Datum|Picture 1 5 Hey Bla 04/05 ~Gallery/pic/tree.jpg <----Problem 2 5 Hey Bla 04/05 ~Gallery/pic/Head.jpg <----its same 3 4 Helo Hehe 03/04 ~Gallery/pic/nuub.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two queries.  Fill up one with all the data from the news table, and one from the pictures table.

In your page load event, populate two private instance variables with the data from both these tables.

In your ASPX page, create two list views, one parent one for the news items, and a child one for the images.  In the News listview "Item_DataBound" event, use FindControl to find the child listview and data item from the pictures datasource.  Then bind the child listview to a subset of the pictures data, which you can do using LINQ.

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLatestNews] AS BEGIN SELECT News.NyhetID, News.Rubrik, News.Nyhet, News.Datum, Picture.Picture FROM Picture RIGHT OUTER JOIN News as News ON News.NyhetID = Picture.NyhetID ORDER BY News.NyhetID DESC END EXEC dbo.GetLatestNews I get something like: 
Row|NyhetID|Rubrik|Nyhet|Datum|Picture 1 5 Hey Bla 04/05 ~Gallery/pic/tree.jpg <----Problem 2 5 Hey Bla 04/05 ~Gallery/pic/Head.jpg <----its same 3 4 Helo Hehe 03/04 ~Gallery/pic/nuub.jpg 
Paul, im only familiar with ObjectDataSource, is it same solution anyway?

Comment: I am suggesting you write two separate queries, and retrieve the data in two hits.  Then filter the pictures for each news item in the OnItemDataBound event. Afraid there is too much here for me to write out the full example.

Comment: Could you help me elsewhere? I really appriciate it, if you got time ofc :)

Comment: I don't have time to write a full example, sorry.  Google "Nested Listviews" and follow an example there.

Comment: Thanks Paul! Ill get back to you if i solve it your way. :)

Comment: Why didn't i think of this, solving the query solved my ASP.NET directly actually, all that was wrong was the query. I really need 1 query with 2 hits! 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLatestNews]
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT TOP 3*
 FROM News
 ORDER BY News.NyhetID DESC
 
 SELECT *
 FROM Picture
 WHERE Picture.NyhetID = NyhetID
END

This easy thing solved it all, thanks paul!

Answer (score 0):

Is the intended behavior to restrict only one picture per article? That is, is the relationship between News and Picture one to many where a News may contain one Picture but a Picture may belong to many News?

I think you might have your table structure backward. Ideally the two tables would be something like below.

```
NEWS
----
NewsID
NewsContent
PictureID

PICTURE
-------
PictureID
PictureURL
```

This way, a News article can only have a single Picture, but the Picture can be referenced in multiple News articles.

Comment: I want to have more than one picture to the same article which means. One article can have multiple pictures but only one specified picture can have a article. Sorry for beeing sloppy on my explantion... So much to explain but hard in text :/